# Python recordlinkage identity

Tags: python, record-linkage

Similar issue as [R recordlinkage identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042584/r-recordlinkage-identity) but in python. The algorithm generates new identity  that do no reflect the correct identity of the records that were matche. Assuming data duplication with a single dataframe.

**PS:** It seems to be okay in the  [data duplication](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/data_deduplication.html)
example

Answer (score 0):

The index column that is generated using pandas needs to be dropped and replaced by the preferred column in the dataframe to use as the identify column

Logic is

```
replace index column with identify column in dataframe
```